# $ab+bc+ca \le 4{\sqrt 3}\Delta$ for a triangle with sides $a$, $b$ and $c$ with area $\Delta$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the sides of a triangle with area $\Delta$, prove that $ab + bc + ca \le 4\sqrt3\Delta$ and prove that the equality holds iff the triangle is equilateral.

I tried to approch this problem in terms of the angles of the triangle $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. As we know that $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\gamma = \Delta$. Thus, the above inequality is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{\sin\alpha} + \frac{1}{\sin\beta} + \frac{1}{\sin\gamma} \le 2\sqrt3$$
I tried many ways to proceed further but was unable to do so. Thank you for your help.